# mapbox javascript custom icon from kml data error message

Tags: javascript, icons, kml, mapbox

i'am working on a mapbox porjekt and with javascript i read out a kml file and add a custom icons, it works but i get this error in the browser console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function mytilemillscript.js:565
(anonymous function) mytilemillscript.js:565
s.LayerGroup.s.Class.extend.eachLayer mapbox.js:2
(anonymous function) mytilemillscript.js:564
s.Mixin.Events.fireEvent mapbox.js:1
t leaflet-omnivore.min.js:1
o
```

here the js code:

```
var greenIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'icon/bergbahn_pitztalgletscher.svg',
    iconSize:     [38, 95], // size of the icon
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
    shadowAnchor: [22, 94]

});


runLayer = omnivore.kml('data/InntalradwegImst-SilzRundeTour14-02.kml').on('ready', function() {

runLayer.eachLayer(function(marker) {
    marker.setIcon( greenIcon);
});

}) .addTo(map);
```

this line causes the error:

```
marker.setIcon( greenIcon);
```

why is that error message?
thanks!

Comment: a sorry, its that line marker.setIcon( greenIcon);

Comment: What does your KML look like?

Answer (score 2):

```
marker.setIcon( greenIcon);
```

Though it's impossible to tell without your data, it's very likely that the problem is that this code has the hard assumption that your KML data *only contains markers*, since you're calling `.setIcon` on *every layer*. So, you probably have a line or polygon in the mix, and since lines and polygons don't have icons, they don't have the `.setIcon` method, hence the error message.